# typescript/javascript draw rect on canvas given translated coordinates relative to original image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, html5-canvas

On the screen, I have an img element that has a css transform: rotate(degree), where degree could be 0, 90, 180, 270, but essentially it can be any degree really.

Meaning, the original image is not actually rotated, just transformed to look rotated.

With that in mind, the user is able to select an area on the TRANSFORMED image, and the output received would be the details of the cropped area relative to the TRANSFORMED image, not the original.

The output of the cropped area would consist of the following info:

- nativeImageWidth
- nativeImageHeight
- positionX
- positionY
- width
- height
- angle (would be 0 if no rotation was done prior to selecting crop area)

What I need to do is to essentially draw a rectangle highlight at the user selected area, and then re-set the original shown img element with the new src data that has the highlighted selected area.

I believe the best way to do this would be to translate the given cropped area position/width/height to what they need to be to the original un-rotated image, and then use those translated dimensions to simply fillRect to that area and then re-set the img shown with context.toDataURL

I am just not sure what the translation formula would look like for the coordinates.

A picture to explain what I said above:
[Picture explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9KPG.png)

I did look around but I can't seem to find a solution quite like the one i am requesting. Most of the things i found on other posts involves using context.rotate() and context.translate() but I was unable to get it working like that either

Essentially what i am looking for is something like this:

```js
function getTranslatedRect(x, y, w, h, angle, nativeImageWidth, nativeImageHeight) {
  let newX = x;
  let newY = y;
  let newWidth = w;
  let newHeight = h;
  let newCanvasWidth = nativeImageWidth;
  let newCanvasHeight = nativeImageHeight;
  
  // do cool math stuff that i am far to un-educated to do (sin? cos? :D)....
  
  newX = 35;
  newY = 320;
  newWidth = 65;
  newHeight = 120;
  
  return {
    newX, newY, newWidth, newHeight, newCanvasWidth, newCanvasHeight
  };
}

let img = document.getElementById('translatedImage');

let translatedRect = getTranslatedRect(60, 35, 120, 65, 90, 350, 500);

let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = translatedRect.newCanvasWidth;
canvas.height = translatedRect.newCanvasHeight;

let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 165, 0, 1)';
ctx.fillRect(translatedRect.newX, translatedRect.newY, translatedRect.newWidth, translatedRect.newHeight);

img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg', 1.0);
```

```css
.canvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}

.rotated {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
translated image with "user highlighted area"
<div class="canvas">
  <img id="translatedImage" class="rotated" src="https://i.ibb.co/fNDs6qQ/Untitled.png" crossorigin="anonymous">

</div>
original image
<div class="canvas">
  
  <img id="originalImage" src="https://i.ibb.co/fNDs6qQ/Untitled.png" crossorigin="anonymous">  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest that you take advantage of the built in CSS matrix operations to perform your calculations.  Towards that end, the following code snippet is a small sample of making use of the CSS transformations via Javascript.

(The stackoverflow code snippet feature did not render the following code properly, so you'll need to copy and paste as an HTML file and then open in the browser to see it in action.)

A couple of notes about the code:

- "box1" is considered the main box, so is simply rotated.
- "box2" is considered a box "attached" to box1, and if simply rotated, will rotate on its own center.  Therefore, before rotating "box2", it must first be moved relative to the center of "box1", then rotated about the "box1" center, and then moved back.

So, to answer your specific question, if you have the coordinates of the smaller box "attached" to the larger box, and know the transformation of the larger box (ie, xy movement, rotation, etc) then internally you can create a DOM object representing the smaller box, apply the reverse of the known rotations of the larger box, and subsequently know how the smaller box relates to the larger box in terms of coordinates...

```
<html><head>

</head><body>

<div id="box1" style="position:absolute; left:50; width:65; top:100; height:120; background: black"></div>
<div id="box2" style="position:absolute; left:55; width:30; top:110; height:60; background: red"></div>

<input id="rotateInput" value="45"></input>
<button onclick="rotate( parseFloat( document.getElementById('rotateInput').value ) )">Rotate</button>

<script>

var currentAngle = 0;

function rotate( rotDeg ) {

  currentAngle += rotDeg;
  
  // Rotating the large box is easy...
  let dom1 = document.getElementById( 'box1' );
  dom1.style.transform = `rotateZ( ${currentAngle}deg )`;

  // Rotating the smaller box is a bit more involved...
  let dom2 = document.getElementById( 'box2' );
  
  console.log( `box2 before rotate: ( L:${box2.offsetLeft}, T:${box2.offsetTop}, W:${box2.offsetWidth}, H:${box2.offsetHeight} )` );
  console.log( box2.getBoundingClientRect() );
  
  dx = ( box2.offsetLeft + box2.offsetWidth / 2 ) - ( box1.offsetLeft + box1.offsetWidth / 2);
  dy = ( box2.offsetTop + box2.offsetHeight / 2 ) - ( box1.offsetTop + box1.offsetHeight / 2);
  
  dom2.style.transform = `
    translateX( ${-dx}px )
    translateY( ${-dy}px )
    rotateZ( ${currentAngle}deg )
    translateY( ${+dy}px )       
    translateX( ${+dx}px )
  `;
  
  console.log( `box2 after rotate: ( L:${box2.offsetLeft}, T:${box2.offsetTop}, W:${box2.offsetWidth}, H:${box2.offsetHeight} )` );
  console.log( box2.getBoundingClientRect() );
  
}

</script>

</body></html>
```